# How to import changes to a EBS volume after sizing it up back to Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, terraform

After running out of space I had to resize my EBS Volume, now I wanted to make the size part of my Terraform configurated and added the following block to the `aws_instance` resource:

```
ebs_block_device {
  device_name = "/dev/sda1"
  volume_size = 32
  volume_type = "gp2"
}
```

Now after running `terraform plan` it wanted to destroy the existing volume, which is terrible. I also tried to import the existing one using `terraform import` but it wanted me to use a different name for the resource which is also not great.

So what is the correct procedure here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`aws_instance` resource docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#encrypted) mention that changes to any EBS block devices will cause the instance to be recreated.

To get around this you can use something other than Terraform to grow the EBS volumes using AWS' new [elastic volumes](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ebs-update-new-elastic-volumes-change-everything/) feature. Terraform also cannot detect changes to any of the attached block devices created in the `aws_instance` resource:

> NOTE: Currently, changes to *_block_device configuration of existing resources cannot be automatically detected by Terraform. After making updates to block device configuration, resource recreation can be manually triggered by using the taint command.

As such you shouldn't need to go back and change anything in your Terraform configuration unless you are wanting to rebuild the instance using Terraform at some point at which point the worry about losing the instance is obviously moot.

However, if for some reason you want to be able to make the change to your Terraform configuration *and* keep the instance from being destroyed then you would need to manipulate your state file.